# How to make object transparent without making its border transparent in INKSCAPE

Tags: transparency

I am creating several objects in INKSCAPE and when I change the transparency of these objects
the whole object becomes transparent, while I would just like that the fill color is.
Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adjust the opacity (=Alpha) of the fill color with the A-slider of the fill color selection dialog

[image]